# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column "name" even though it exists in my db table

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, migration

Error even though the column exists in the migration table.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in
> 'field list' (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`name`, `description`,
> `statuse_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Padaryti pietus,
> fsd, 2, 2021-07-07 09:45:47, 2021-07-07 09:45:47))

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('task_name', 128);
    $table->text('task_description');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('statuse_id');
    $table->foreign('statuse_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Task Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
   [
       'task_name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:128'],
       'task_description' => ['required'],
       'statuse_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
   ]
   );
   if ($validator->fails()) {
       $request->flash();
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
   }
   
   $task = new Task;
   $task->name = $request->task_name;
   $task->description = $request->task_description;
   $task->statuse_id = $request->statuse_id;
   $task->save();

   return redirect()->route('task.index')
       ->with('success_message', 'New task created successfuly');
 }
```

**Task create.blade.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('task.store') }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" 
               value="{{old('task_name')}}">
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Add a task name</small>
    </div>
    <label>Description:</label>
    <textarea name="task_description" id="summernote">
        {!!old('task_description')!!}
    </textarea>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Add task description</small>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="statuse_id">
            @foreach ($statuses as $statuse)
            <option value="{{$statuse->id}}">{{$statuse->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Select a status</small>
    </div>
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn">ADD</button>
</form>
```

I see task_name in my DB table in PhpMyAdmin. What is the solution to this error in this situation?

Comment: Your `Task` has `name`, not `task_name`

Answer (score 2):

So, for repeating it once again but just to explain a bit more, in your migration, you have set it as `task_name`, what you have to do in your TaskController is just name,  so, changing it to `task_name` is required to do the task.

Also, this is the reason for receiving the error of column not found.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert in the database data in the column `name` while it doesn't exist.

Change this line:

```
   $task->name = $request->task_name;
```

into

```
   $task->task_name = $request->task_name;
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
$task->name = $request->task_name;
```

with

```
$task->task_name = $request->task_name;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it